# Instantiating Subclasses from dropdown option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a page that allows a user to run a report. I'm using Rails 5. My reporting page allows the user to select different report types. So, the user has a drop down with the following options: `Tax`, `Order`, `Refund`, and so on.

Depending on their selection, I will instantiate a subclass of my `Reports::Report` class for their selected option.

Currently, I am doing this:

```
if params[:report_type] == "Tax"
    Reports::Tax.new.run
elsif params[:report_type] == "Order"
    Reports::Order.new.run
elsif params[:report_type] == "Refund"
    Reports::Refund.new.run
end
```

How can I restructure this code so that I don't have an endlessly long list of conditionals for running certain report types? What's the more OOP approach to solving this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really that different but you could use a hash, e.g. `{ "Tax" => Reports::Tax, "Order" => Reports::Order }[params[:report_type]]`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your options values map to the exact classes you have defined in your Reports module, (I mean for example, your select options are `Tax`, `Order`, `Refund`, and you have exact `Reports::Tax`, `Reports::Order`, `Reports::Refund` defined) you can try the following

```rb
begin
  report = Object.const_get("Reports::#{params[:report_type]}")
  report.new.run
rescue 
  # error handler for not existing report type
end
```